# play/stop hidden audio track

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I have an ASIDE element that I set to slide in and out from the right when a button is clicked with Jquery UI.  It's toggled closed by default.  It contains HTML5 AUDIO.  I want the audio to play from the beginning when the slide is opened and stop when it's closed so that it's like a background music track that only plays when the slide is open.  I was hoping the audio wouldn't play with its parent element's display set to "none", but that's not the case.

I actually have two buttons that control the sliding element.  One is a toggle button, and the other is inside the sliding element as a close button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AnsExpl_btn a").click(function() {
    $("aside").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
  });
  $("#AnsExpl_x a").click(function() {
    $("aside").hide("slide", { direction: "right" });
  });
});
```

I've tried different possible Jquery/Javascript solutions that I found online, but nothing has worked.  Any help would be appreciated because I think I've exhausted Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pause and play in sync with the buttons - assuming your audio element is obtained in variable `audio`:

```
var audio = $('#bgtrack')[0]; // get native audio element

$("#AnsExpl_btn a").click(function() {
    $("aside").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
});

$("#AnsExpl_x a").click(function() {
    $("aside").hide("slide", { direction: "right" });
    audio.pause();
});
```

Setting position is asynchronous and if done properly you should listen to the `seeked` event and then play it:

```
audio.addEventListener('seeked', function() {this.play()}, false);

$("#AnsExpl_btn a").click(function() {
    $("aside").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" });
    audio.currentTime = 0;
});
```

**Update: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/5hNXd/)**

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but I'm probably doing something wrong.  I'm trying to add it to an external .js file.  I noticed if I set the audio to autoplay and then click the link to activate the slide, the audio stops, even if I have no code to do so.  I also have multiple audio tags on the page, but I'm trying to control one with #track.

Comment: @Maxor it's a bit hard to get the overview without the related code. Do you have a chance to set up a fiddle so we can dig deeper into it?

Comment: This is my first time using jsfiddle.  Here is the basic layout of the site.  http://jsfiddle.net/Q7NQ6/1/  JSfiddle kept giving some post error when I had an AUDIO tag in the code, so I had to remove it.  It would've gone right above the closing ASIDE tag and included id="bgtrack" with two sources track.mp3 and track.ogg.  I will also have a few other audio cues on the page that are already working correctly, but are unrelated to this button or slide.  They're more like sound effects, while the one I'm trying to add will be like background music that only plays when ASIDE is visible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7NQ6/3/ Here is a new link with AUDIO added.  Noscript was causing the error in jsfiddle.  I'm using Firefox, by the way.  It seems the slide doesn't work in IE11 for some reason in jsfiddle, but it works on my actual site.

Comment: @Maxor thanks, just a problem: the audio files are linking to the jsfiddle site (which of course does not have the audio files). I added a link to a sound effect and updated the fiddle with the code from the answer. The only thing missing was that you needed to obtain the audio element as stated. Short samples sometimes throw off the buffering mechanism in browsers but you should be able to see that it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it's almost working.  When I open the slide to play the audio track, it only plays about a second of it and then stops playing.  The audio file included in jsfiddle is probably too short to notice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hNXd/2/ I've gotten it to work by moving the audio code out of the sliding section.  Audio is playing fine now.  I also added if/else code to the jquery to get the music to play or stop depending on if the slide was open or closed when the toggle button was clicked because otherwise the music kept restarting.